# WPF Video loop from point a to b

Tags: wpf

Is there any way to loop a video in WPF from point A to B?
A & B indicates time.
For example i want to loop a video & loop starts from 1 minute of the video and ends at 2 minute of video.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

XAML

```
<MediaElement x:Name="MyVideo"
            Loaded="MyVideo_Loaded"
            LoadedBehavior="Manual"
            Source="C:\SomeFolder\SomeVideo.mp4" />
```

Codebehind

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private DispatcherTimer dispatcherTimer;

    /// <summary>
    /// Initializes a new instance of the MainWindow class.
    /// </summary>
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        //Set up the DispatcherTimer with a Tick interval of 1 minute
        dispatcherTimer = new DispatcherTimer();
        dispatcherTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(dispatcherTimer_Tick);
        dispatcherTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 1, 0);
    }

    //Occurs when MediaElement is Loaded
    private void MyVideo_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Set MediaElement Position to 1 minute and Play
        MyVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        MyVideo.Play();

        //Start the timer
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }

    //Occurs every Tick
    private void dispatcherTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //At the end of a Tick period, reset the MediaElement Position and Play again
        MyVideo.Position = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1);
        MyVideo.Play();

        //Disable/reset the timer
        dispatcherTimer.IsEnabled = false;

        //Restart the timer
        dispatcherTimer.Start();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked.One last question, what if i want to stop looping video at press of Right Arrow key & start playing video from the end of the loop? I am totally new to WPF. any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you again.

Comment: Take a look at the KeyDown/KeyUp events of the Window. They'll let you capture the Enter keypress, then you'll need to disable the DispatcherTimer, set the MediaElement Position to the end of the loop and play the MediaElement.